In Twilio studio, can I use the messaging service, incoming SMS and wait and reply all on the same number?
is it possible to do all of the below in Twilio studio, for the same number.
Requirements:

Add the number to a messaging service (especially needed due to regulatory compliance for USA)
If an sms is received and there IS a waiting ‘send and wait’ widget which matches that number, trigger the wait and reply system
If an sms is received and there IS NOT a waiting ‘send and wait’ widget, process that response separately (in the way you would if you attached nodes to the ‘incoming message’ trigger).

I know how to do all 3 of the above things individually. What I need to know is if I can have all 3 for the same number, because, as far as I know so far:
Requirements 1 and 2 and mutually exclusive: If your number is attached to a messaging service it won't be picked up by a waiting send and reply
Requirements 2 and 3 are mutually exclusive: If you attach a node to the incoming sms path of a studio flow with a ‘send and wait’ widget, the sms will not trigger the waiting ‘send and wait’ widget.
Admittedly it has been a while since I tried to solve it again and I know Twilio are always improving and updating. Help greatly appreciated!

Twilio Evangelist here.
Take into account that Studio has the same functionalities with or without a Messaging Service, If you have a 'Send & Wait for Reply' widget active, any incoming messages from the same number should be routed to that widget. If there is no active session, the message should start a new flow execution.
It's important to mention that there are no issues with integrating a Messaging Service with a Flow that uses "Send & Wait for Reply", Even if it is the first widget used in the Incoming Message path, it works fine.
The only known behavior while using a Messaging Service through a Flow is when you create a Studio execution using REST API, and it's detailed in the following article Why Does the Send & Wait for Reply Widget Stop Collecting the Users Response and Creates a New Execution for US A2P-Registered 10DLC Numbers.
It's highly recommended to verify the Messaging Service is properly configured and connected to the flow to ensure responses are received by the mentioned widget, if you continue to experience issues, it's helpful to create a support ticket attaching some Executions SID's "FNxxxxxxxxx" and that way our team will be able to properly troubleshoot the behavior.
